# How to define two different database users in Quarkus for Liquibase

Tags: mysql, liquibase, quarkus

currently I'm trying to create a REST-Client with Quarkus and it's really amazing how cool this framework is. But now I'm having some problems with Liquibase.

I want Liquibase to access the database with an other user, than the datasource. In spring boot it would be something like this.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mariadb://...
    username: <app_user>
    password: ${DB_PASSWORD}
  liquibase:
    default-schema: my_schema
    user: <admin_user>
    password: ${DB_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
```

Is it possible to configure this in Quarkus too?

Comment: One quick way is to configure a datasource for this purpose and have liquibase use that datasource, with `quarkus.liquibase."named-data-sources".xxx` configurations. The obvious drawback is that you carry this object for the entire life of the application. You can configure the datasource with minimal resources to make it as light as possible, but it is still awkward. Personally, I am separating the Liquibase scripts from the application. Have you seen the API of the injectable `LiquibaseFactory` object?

Comment: I will have a look, thank you.

Comment: Were you able to get this to work Valentin?  If so, please consider closing this question if your question has been answered.  If you need more help on liquibase, the forum (forum.liquibase.org) or liquibase discord server (discord.gg/9yBwMtj) is pretty useful. – ronak 16 mins